# How to implement push mail notification for exchange server?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want my Exchange mail server to give notifications of incoming mails to the mobile device running the mail application.

Does EWS API provide any method to implement it? Could anyone please help me to understand how shall I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push notification sample application contains two components. The first component is the client Web service that listens for and retrieves notification events. This component also provides responses to notify the Client Access server as to whether the subscription should be maintained. The second component initiates the subscription with the Client Access server. It identifies the client Web service endpoint and other information that is required to configure the subscription.

**The following prerequisites are needed to build and use the Push Notification Sample Application:**

- Microsoft.NET Framework
- MicrosoftVisual Studio .NET
- MicrosoftInternet Information Services (IIS)
- MS Exchange 2010

The `types.xsd` and `messages.xsd` schema files that are found in the EWS virtual directory of the computer that is running Exchange 2010.

**To build the push notification client Web services application****

1. Open the client Web services project.
2. Navigate to the directory in which the Exchange 2010 Web Services SDK is installed, open the `Samples\PushNotification\PushNotificationClient\` folder, and double-click the `PushNotificationClient.sln` file.
3. From the Build menu, select Build Web Site.
4. Publish the Web site to an IIS virtual directory

**To set up and build the subscriber application**

1. Navigate to the directory in which the Exchange 2010 Web Services SDK is installed, open the `Samples\PushNotification\PushNotificationSubscriber\` folder, and double-click the `PushNotificationSubscriber.csproj` file.
2. Update the `ExchangeServiceBindingUrl` property to identify the location of the Exchange Web service.
3. Update the `ExchangeServiceBindingCredentials` property to identify the name, password, and domain of the user whose mailbox will be monitored for events.
4. Update the `PushSubscriptionRequestTypeURL` property to identify the location of the client Web service that will receive the event notifications. This URL is defined by the location of the client Web service.
5. From the Build menu, select **Build Solution**.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from these threads : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73834/EWS-Mail-Notifier#/KB/exchange/ewsconsolenotify.aspx#_comments

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21164/Exchange-2007-Push-Notifications-Using-WCF

A Complete process is given in the above two threads describing how to set up push notifications for MS Exchange server